# constuct mixed list

Tags: list, lisp

Hi everyone I am trying to construct a mixed list with letters and numbers. For example when you call the funciton (inc-list1 '(cat 4 dog 3 x 5)) => (cat 5 dog 4 x 6). I am pretty sure the logic is right, so i think i am missing something from the syntax. Here is my code

```
(defun inc-list1 (list)
      (cond  ((null list)
              nil
              )
            (numberp (first list) 
                     (cons ( + 1   (first list)) (inc-list1 (rest list)))
             )
            (T 
             cons (first list) (inc-list1 (rest list))
             )
       )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various typos in your code. Here is a fixed version

```lisp
(defun inc-list1 (list)
  (cond  ((null list)
          nil
          )
         ((numberp (first list))
          (cons ( + 1   (first list)) (inc-list1 (rest list)))
          )
         (t
          (cons (first list) (inc-list1 (rest list)))
          )
         )
  )
```

Note the added parens around the `numberp` and `cons` function calls and the `t` in lower case.

Answer (score 1):

An example of how you could have approached the problem:

```
(defun mapcar-if (list test if-true &optional (otherwise #'identity))
  (mapcar
   #'(lambda (x)
       (funcall
        (if (funcall test x)
            if-true
          otherwise) x)) list))

(mapcar-if '(cat 4 dog 3 x 5) #'numberp #'1+)
```

Which would make the function a little bit more useful in other situations too.

Your code:

1. `(T cons ...)` doesn't do what you think it does. You probably wanted to *call* `cons` rather then simply mention it. Mentioning it in the way you did has no effect and no side effect (it would have side effect, if the symbol cons was unbound - i.e. you'd receive an error). Whatever happens next is the result of the previous error. Calling `(first list)` has no side effect too (in your case).
2. "Consing" the list in the way you did isn't a particularly good technique. Because this technique is already implemented in other functions (like `mapcar`, `reduce` etc.) They were written with the purpose in mind to reduce the amount of text you have to type to write a program, and to make it easier to read, once you have written it. ;)